# how do i get my input to keep adding values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
$(onReady);

function onReady() {
    console.log('log inside of onReady');
    $(".calculatorNum").on('click', buttonClicked);
}//end of onReady

function buttonClicked() {
    console.log('buttonClicked');
    var input = $("#inputField").val($(this).text());
    input += input;

}
```

```css
button {
    height:30px;
    width:30px
}

#clearButton{
    width:64px
}

#inputField{
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    height:2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="scripts/scripts.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
        <div class="numContainer">
            <input id = 'inputField' type="text" placeholder="input">
            <br>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">1</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">2</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">3</button>
            <button id = 'addButton' class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">+</button>
            <br>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">4</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">5</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">6</button>
            <button id = 'subButton' class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">-</button>
            <br>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">7</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">8</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">9</button>
            <button id = 'multButton' class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">X</button>
            <br>
            <button  id = 'clearButton' class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">Clear</button>
            <button  class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">/</button>
            <button  class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">=</button>
        </div>

        <!-- <button id = 'addButton' class ='calculatorButton' type="button" name="button">+</button>
        <button id = 'subButton' class ='calculatorButton' type="button" name="button">-</button>
        <button id = 'multButton' class ='calculatorButton' type="button" name="button">X</button>
        <button id = 'divButton' class ='calculatorButton' type="button" name="button">/</button> -->


    </body>
</html>
```

I want that everytime i click on a button, in the input field it keeps adding values according to the text of the button i clicked.

Comment: What SO does here is actually to help _us_ answer your question. You should add more Information and not just some gibberish at the bottom of your post.

Comment: You'll have to think about the math functions you want to be executed. So one function for each math operation, binded to the relevant button. You will also need to `parseInt()` the button text to perform math operations.

Comment: So you just want text added or you mean calculator options like addition, subtraction to be done?

Comment: Just get current value of text and add button value and resign to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a global variable:

```
var input="";
function buttonClicked() {
console.log('buttonClicked');
$("#inputField").val((input+=$(this).text()));
}
```

Some explanations:

Youre declaring the input variable inside of buttonClicked. Therefore it is garbage collected after the function has run, so input is lost after each click. If you want to prevent this, make input global trough declaring it in the global scope. Then you can append the buttons value ( += ) to input, and show this value. If you want input to be a Number, you may do:

```
var input=0;
function buttonClicked() {
console.log('buttonClicked');
$("#inputField").val((input+=+$(this).text()));
}
```

Comment: mmm... Did you test this last one? I would say `input+=parseInt($(this).text())`.... This would be good for addition only... And it should not trigger on math operator buttons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Math operation will fail if you try to add a string to an integer. It will end in a string.

Comment: Maybe... I never used it like this. ;)

Comment: @louys patrice bessette https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

Comment: Great! Thanks ;)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys. I couldn't figure it out so I just changed it to a p tag and styled it to look like input. Ways easier to append

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying this:

**Note: Just get current value of text and add button value and resign to text.**

```js
$(onReady);

function onReady() {
    console.log('log inside of onReady');
    $(".calculatorNum").on('click', buttonClicked);
}//end of onReady

function buttonClicked() {
    console.log('buttonClicked');
   $("#inputField").val($("#inputField").val()+$(this).text());
}
```

```css
button {
    height:30px;
    width:30px
}

#clearButton{
    width:64px
}

#inputField{
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    height:2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="scripts/scripts.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
        <div class="numContainer">
            <input id = 'inputField' type="text" placeholder="input">
            <br>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">1</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">2</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">3</button>
            <button id = 'addButton' class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">+</button>
            <br>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">4</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">5</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">6</button>
            <button id = 'subButton' class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">-</button>
            <br>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">7</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">8</button>
            <button class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">9</button>
            <button id = 'multButton' class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">X</button>
            <br>
            <button  id = 'clearButton' class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">Clear</button>
            <button  class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">/</button>
            <button  class ='calculatorNum' type="button" name="button">=</button>
        </div>

        <!-- <button id = 'addButton' class ='calculatorButton' type="button" name="button">+</button>
        <button id = 'subButton' class ='calculatorButton' type="button" name="button">-</button>
        <button id = 'multButton' class ='calculatorButton' type="button" name="button">X</button>
        <button id = 'divButton' class ='calculatorButton' type="button" name="button">/</button> -->


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some more explanation on what you changed in the code would be helpfull to OP.

Comment: @Govind this works here on stack overflow, but when i paste it over to my editor and run it, if click the button 5 the input value goes to 55 and it does that for every button i press

Comment: This code is fine ,I think problem is some where else.

Comment: @MoisesMiguel: Did you at least removed your old code?